# Get path of a file from Resources.resx

Tags: c#, visual-studio, logging, file-io, resx

How do you get the path from a file in the Resources.resx file?

I have the following code:

```
var value = Properties.Resources.ErrorLog;
```

Where ErrorLog is .txt file. The code returns the content of the file not the path. Right-clicking and see where it is located is not an option since the project is used on more than one computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no <strike>spoon</strike> path.

These resources are embedded in your EXE file; they don't exist as separate filers at runtime.

Comment: What about setting the `Copy to Output Directory` property to `Copy always` of the text file resource... would that work?

Comment: @Super: Yes.  (but it wouldn't be embedded)